# Reporting using TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am required to print two reports in the following format:

```
             Header 1                                    
             Header 2              DateTime

SN     Employee/Manager    Salary    Bonus
A        John/Susan        60000     5000
B        Jenny/Gary        70000    10000
Total       2             130000    15000

Total Bonus   : 15000
Total Records : 2


             Header 1                                    
             Header 2              DateTime

SN           Employee/Manager    Salary    Bonus
Successful             
A            John/Susan          60000     5000
Subtotal: 1

Struggling
B            John/Susan          70000    10000
Subtotal: 1

Total            2              130000    15000
```

I have all the required information present in a single table.

Before coding, I wanted to ask the TSQL experts out there if this is something that is possible in TSQL? If not, I'll use a procedural programming language to accomplish this.

EDIT1: I don't need this to display at the front end. Just have to dump it to .txt file.
The schema for this example would be:
SN Employee Manager Salary Bonus

Comment: we can do using T-sql with ROLL UP option but it is upto you how to bind in front end using required parameters

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you included the table schema.

Comment: I just added some more information Nathan

Answer (score 0):

i'm just showing you with some sample data how you can proceed in T-Sql way but it's all depends on your requirement how to bind the columns in the front end

just an assumption based on your requirement we can do with grouping or ROLLUP

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(SN varchar(5),NAME NVARCHAR(MAX),datee date,sal money,bonus money)

insert INTO @t SELECT 'A','John/Susan','2012-01-02',6000,5000
insert INTO @t SELECT 'B','Jenny/Gary','2012-01-02',7000,10000

SELECT SN,count(SN)SubTotal,
  Name,
  (datee),
  SUM (sal)salary,SUM(bonus) Bonus
FROM @t 
GROUP BY 
  ROLLUP((SN,NAME, datee))

SELECT SN,count(SN)SubTotal,
  Name,
  (datee),
  SUM (sal)salary,SUM(bonus) Bonus
FROM @t 
GROUP BY 
  GROUPING SETS((SN,NAME ,datee), ())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try hard enough you can accomplish almost anything in SQL, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea. The purpose of SQL is to return a set of data in tabular form. To get something like you want, you basically are returning a single column varchar result set. This is not a good idea. You should be returning the raw query results to some client that does that kind of formatting. That's why we have Reporting Services, Crystal Reports and C#.

Yes ROLLUP could accomplish the subtotals, but using that is way more trouble than it's worth to make the data easy to understand. On top of that, you are showing page headers and footers in your example, and that's not at all easy to do using TSQL.

My advice, use a tool that is better suited for this.